# how do I make seamless reflections on curved Geometry? (See picture)

Tags: shaders, edges, geometry, reflection, roughness

How do I line up the reflections on this geometry so it is more seamless? As you can see in the picture it doesn't quite line up.

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, hard to guess what's the problem here, maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Looks like that the vertices at the seam are not connected. If that does not help, try recalculate the normals.

Comment: @quellenform recalculating the normals worked! Thank you (: